# Make variable from range

Tags: vba, excel

This part of code is opening an Excel file and loading the data from range D4:D5 to one master table.

```
GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "D4:D5",   Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False
```

I want the D4:D5 range use as variable that will be load from array.

```
Dim nazov(1 To 2) As String   

nazov(1) = "D4:D5"
nazov(2) = "S4:S5"   


For i = 2 To UBound(nazov)


GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "nazov(i)", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i)), True, False


        Next i
```

But this doesn't work. Could you please help me with the code?

Comment: I believe you're trying to pull two cells' contents to one variable. This won't work unless you specify what value (sum, product, concatenation, range) you're interested in.

Comment: "nazov(i)" - if i change the D4:D5 with variable .. the variable doesnt return the D4:D5 value ...

Comment: No this is content only from one cell. D4:D5 return value from cell D5.  S4:S5 from S5 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start loop from `i = 1` and remove `"` so that you can pass the value of the array `nazov`

```
For i = 1 To UBound(nazov)
GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", nazov(i), Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i)), True, False
Next i
```

Comment: Alternativly: `For i = LBound(nazov) To UBound(nazov)`, that way you'll get the full array, no matter how it's defined.